# Adding highscore to array using insertion sort results in duplication

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I've been scratching my head over this for awhile now. I'm quite new to programming, so my code may not be that efficient, but it's killing me that I can't figure out what's going wrong.

The goal is to compare 'uScore' (the score of the game just played, where lower is better) to the sorted list of highscores stored in the array of objects 'records', using records[i].getName() to retrieve the score at that position. I then mark the position where 'uScore' is to be inserted using 'insertScoreHere', then shift everything below it in the array down by one place. I then set the value of the score at 'insertScoreHere' to uScore, and the name to 'uName' (player name from game just played).

```
public void sortWinners() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (uScore < records[i].getScore()) {
            insertScoreHere = i;
            i = 10; //this is terrible i know
        }
    }

    for (int i = 9; i > insertScoreHere; i--) {
        records[i] = records[i-1];
    }

    records[insertScoreHere].setName(uName);
    records[insertScoreHere].setScore(uScore);
}
```

Now if the player name from the most recent game is 'sam', and his score is '8', and the array is empty to start with, this is what is happening (below is the array 'records'):

```
 NAME: sam, SCORE: 8

 NAME: sam, SCORE: 8

 NAME: , SCORE: 0

 NAME: , SCORE: 0

 NAME: , SCORE: 0

 NAME: , SCORE: 0

 NAME: , SCORE: 0

 NAME: , SCORE: 0

 NAME: , SCORE: 0

 NAME: , SCORE: 0
```

I've logged everything as much as I can, adding this to my code:

```
public void sortWinners() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (uScore < records[i].getScore()) {
            insertScoreHere = i;
            i = 10;
        }
    }

    Log.v("ARRAY", "PLACE TO INSERT SCORE: " + insertScoreHere);

    for (int i = 9; i > insertScoreHere; i--) {

        Log.v("ARRAY", "BEFORE ITERATION I = " + i + ": " +
                " | " + records[0].getScore() +
                " | " + records[1].getScore() +
                " | " + records[2].getScore() +
                " | " + records[3].getScore() +
                " | " + records[4].getScore() +
                " | " + records[5].getScore() +
                " | " + records[6].getScore() +
                " | " + records[7].getScore() +
                " | " + records[8].getScore() +
                " | " + records[9].getScore());
        records[i] = records[i-1];

        Log.v("ARRAY", " AFTER ITERATION I = " + i + ": " +
                      " | " + records[0].getScore() +
                      " | " + records[1].getScore() +
                      " | " + records[2].getScore() +
                      " | " + records[3].getScore() +
                      " | " + records[4].getScore() +
                      " | " + records[5].getScore() +
                      " | " + records[6].getScore() +
                      " | " + records[7].getScore() +
                      " | " + records[8].getScore() +
                      " | " + records[9].getScore());
    }
    records[insertScoreHere].setName(uName);
    records[insertScoreHere].setScore(uScore);

    Log.v("ARRAY", "AFTER SORTING");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Log.v("ARRAY", "NAME: " + records[i].getName() + ", SCORE: " + records[i].getScore());
    }
}
```

Here's an example of the result of the logging. Say we have a populated array (where duplicates have already occurred), e.g:

```
NAME: milfred, SCORE: 1

NAME: milfred, SCORE: 1

NAME: timmy, SCORE: 3

NAME: john, SCORE: 5

NAME: sam, SCORE: 7

NAME: dhshs, SCORE: 8

NAME: , SCORE: 0

NAME: , SCORE: 0

NAME: , SCORE: 0

NAME: , SCORE: 0
```

Now let's say the next game that is played has a score of '6' and a player name 'stringray'. This is what my logging returns:

```
PLACE TO INSERT SCORE: 4

BEFORE ITERATION I = 9:  | 1 | 1 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 8 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0

 AFTER ITERATION I = 9:  | 1 | 1 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 8 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0

BEFORE ITERATION I = 8:  | 1 | 1 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 8 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0

 AFTER ITERATION I = 8:  | 1 | 1 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 8 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0

BEFORE ITERATION I = 7:  | 1 | 1 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 8 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0

 AFTER ITERATION I = 7:  | 1 | 1 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 8 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0

BEFORE ITERATION I = 6:  | 1 | 1 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 8 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0

 AFTER ITERATION I = 6:  | 1 | 1 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 8 | 8 | 0 | 0 | 0

BEFORE ITERATION I = 5:  | 1 | 1 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 8 | 8 | 0 | 0 | 0

 AFTER ITERATION I = 5:  | 1 | 1 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 7 | 8 | 0 | 0 | 0



AFTER SORTING

NAME: milfred, SCORE: 1

NAME: milfred, SCORE: 1

NAME: timmy, SCORE: 3

NAME: john, SCORE: 5

NAME: stingray, SCORE: 6

NAME: stingray, SCORE: 6

NAME: dhshs, SCORE: 8

NAME: , SCORE: 0

NAME: , SCORE: 0

NAME: , SCORE: 0
```

And lastly, here at my data types:

```
String uName;
int uScore;
playerRecord records[] = new playerRecord[10];
```

playerRecord:

```
public class playerRecord {
    private String name;
    private int score;

    public playerRecord(String input_name, int input_score) {
        name = input_name;
        score = input_score;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setName(String set_name) {
        name = set_name;
    }

    public void setScore(int set_score) {
        score = set_score;
    }
}
```

Populating playerRecord:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            records[i] = new playerRecord("", (0));
        }
```

I hope I've been able to illustrate the issue properly. If any other details are needed please let me know.

Comment: [`Arrays.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int[])) is your friend, also where you have `//this is terrible i know` I think the keyword you are looking for is [`break`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

Comment: ah cheers for the tips. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having issues with memory pointers. Your array of 10 scores is actually an array of 10 pointers to playerRecord objects. I know it doesn't look like it, but this is what is happening behind the scenes when you have an array of objects.

The two duplicated elements in the array, after executing the sort operation, are actually addressing the same piece of memory!

Let's say i=4; and insertScoreHere = 3.

```
records[i] = records[i-1];

# records[4] = records[3]; 
# BUT what actually happens here is records[4] is now pointing to the 
# same piece of memory as records[3]. So then:
# records[4] => memory_address_x
# records[3] => memory_address_x

records[insertScoreHere].setName(uName);
records[insertScoreHere].setScore(uScore); 

#so now this code: records[3].setName(uName); is actually modifying 
#the same piece of memory as records[4].
```

**Solution #1:**

Swap the pointers around as you do the sort. I'm going to use the object at i==9 since that one gets wiped anyway.

```
public void sortWinners() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (uScore < records[i].getScore()) {
            insertScoreHere = i;
            i = 10; //this is terrible i know
        }
    }

    # EDIT 1: lets save this record for reuse
    playerRecord temp = records[9]; 
    for (int i = 9; i > insertScoreHere; i--) {
        records[i] = records[i-1];
    }

    # EDIT 2: change the record to point to a separate record
    records[insertScoreHere] = temp; 
    # ^ this index now points to a separate record from records[i] 
    records[insertScoreHere].setName(uName);
    records[insertScoreHere].setScore(uScore);
}
```

**Solution #2:**

Another way to avoid messing with memory pointers will be to copy the data from one record to another:

```
public void sortWinners() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (uScore < records[i].getScore()) {
            insertScoreHere = i;
            i = 10; //this is terrible i know
        }
    }

    for (int i = 9; i > insertScoreHere; i--) {
        records[i].setName(records[i-1].getName());  # EDIT 1 **
        records[i].setScore(records[i-1].getScore());# EDIT 2 **
    }

    records[insertScoreHere].setName(uName);
    records[insertScoreHere].setScore(uScore);
}
```

Comment: I've updated it and added a second solution, with code. The second solution avoids the duplicate memory pointer assignments caused by the code "records[i] = records[i-1];"

Comment: wow thanks so much for that, really easy to understand. I went with the second solution!

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes about with these lines when you want to insert your new score

```
records[insertScoreHere].setName(uName);
records[insertScoreHere].setScore(uScore);
```

What this is actually doing is replacing the name and score of the `playerRecord` that is at that index. Which has also the same object which you have now shuffled to the next index `(insertScoreHere + 1)`

To show you this all you need to do is print the address of the player records in your array:

```
playerRecord@996db8, playerRecord@996db8, playerRecord@163006a, playerRecord@1be847c, ...
```

This is after I have called your `sortWinners` method once - you can see that the first two elements in the array reference the same object `playerRecord@996db8`

To fix this you just need to insert the new score at that index by calling this

```
records[insertScoreHere] = new PlayerRecord(uName, uScore)
```

---

You might also want to review the [naming conventions for Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)